# Cannot read property 'whenReady' of undefined

Tags: express, electron

Al querer ejecutar el comando "node index.js" me devuelve el error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'whenReady' of undefined**

Soy nuevo en electron...Lo que estoy buscando hacer es iniciar el servidor express con la ventana de electron abierta. Mi idea es ir haciendo pruebas a los `methods` `GET` y `POST` desde POSTMAN,
Para luego imprimir los resultados en la ventana mismo con vue.

código:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors    = require('cors');

const api           = express();
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
global.conn         = require('./api/config/conn');

const {app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const corsOptions   = {
    "origin": '*',
    "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
    "preflightContinue": false,
    "allowedHeaders": ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}

api.use( cors(corsOptions) );
api.use( bodyParser.json() )

// ----------------------------------

setInterval(() => {

    app.get('/actions/print', async function (req, res) {
        let action  = require('./api/servicios/actions')
        let response    = await action.obtenerDato()      
    
      res.set(['Content-Type', 'application/json']);
      res.send(response);
    });
    
}, 5000);

// -----------------------------------

api.listen(3000, () => {

    console.log("Backend working");

})

// -- Ventana app
function createWindow () {

    const win = new BrowserWindow ({
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false
        }
    })
    win.loadFile('index.html')   
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

// -- Fin ventana app
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue desinstalar electrón y volver a instalarlo global.

`npm i -g electron` y se cambio `app.get('/actions/print', async function (req, res)` por `**api**.get('/actions/print', async function (req, res)`

Gracias